# if updated_at then display updated at if not created_at

Tags: php, laravel

If the ad has been updated I want the updated_at displayed. If not I want the created_at to be displayed

```
 @if($ad->updated_at)
  <span><h6>Uppdaterat den: {{$ad->updated_at}}</h6></span>
  @else <span><h6>{{$ad->created_at}}</h6></span>
  @endif
```

But this doesn't work, this always displays the updated at. When I go to my table, I just created a new ad and the updated_at and created_at shows the same timestamps.

Comment: `this always displays the updated at`...what does it display when `updated_at` doesn't exist then? What is `$ad->updated_at` actually populated with in the `$ad` object, when no update has been made yet? Is it null? Or the property is undefined? Or something else (e.g. blank string perhaps)?

Comment: try this `@if($ad->updated_at != null) {{$ad->updated_at}} @endif`

Comment: @user15070659 that also always displays the updated at

Comment: @ADyson when I go to my table, I just created a new ad and the updated_at and created_at shows the same timestamps, it's not null

Comment: @CarlMenger that's important information which should be in your question. Please edit the question.

Comment: @ADyson you are right with that one, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
@if($ad->updated_at && ($ad->updated_at != $ad->created_at) )
    <span><h6>Uppdaterat den: {{$ad->updated_at}}</h6></span>
@else 
    <span><h6>{{$ad->created_at}}</h6></span>
@endif
```